# T4-Templates for Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6

where to find the T4-Templates the EF Tools for VS use for doing Reverse-Engineering with Code First?

I can find the the Templates for Generating Classes out of an EDMX but not for the new Code-First-Option...

wishes,
Manfred

Answer (score 1):

You can install and modify them from NUGET. Here are the instructions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn753860